# Error in fitting Natural Spline in R

Tags: r, splines

I'm fitting a natural spline model and I get the errors below. Can you help me understand and solve the error below?

`Error in double(nx * ncoef) : vector size cannot be NA`

`In addition: Warning message:
In nx * ncoef : NAs produced by integer overflow`

Unfortunately, I cannot upload the dataset and unfortunately, you could not replicate my code. Instead, I'll try to explain my code as much as I can:

Below is the code that I run to fit a natural spline fit:

```
fit.temp <- lm(y ~ ns(x,knots = seq(1, nrow(data), by = 10)),data = data)
```

In my dataset, x is a sequence from 1 to the number of rows in data which is 424742.

I know this question is somewhat a vague question, but after spending a lot of energy, I didn't have any luck figuring out what this error is and how to solve it.

Thanks very much,

Comment: Thanks @Ferdinand.kraft for your comment. Please notice that I don't define any of them, this is the error R returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere within the code, it is trying to multiply two integers but the result is greater than the maximum integer that can be stored on your machine (`.Machine$integer.max`).

Without delving too much into the code, your inputs must be too big for this tool. Either work with a smaller `data`, or fewer knots by increasing the `by` argument to `seq`. Roughly, `(nrow(data)^2 / .Machine$integer.max` should give you a lower bound on how big `by` should be.

Comment: Hi @flodel, thanks for the answer. The data has about 425000 observations.